# Can PHP easily open file outside the WWW on a Unix filesystem?

Tags: php, apache, unix

I have a web app where my php reads a file from the windows file system

```
$file = file_get_contents("C:/windows/blah.ini");
```

No permissions or whatever hacks necessary, it just works perfectly.

I will soon need to install my app on a Unix OS (Ubuntu for now) and i was wondering if this can also work as well or do i have to deal w/ some work arounds to do this since i'm accessing a file outside WWW directory and in the OS directory..

Regards to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to deal with [permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions).

Your best bet is to install Ubuntu and just give it a whirl. Web developers should have some knowledge of Linux anyway. It cannot be taught, it has be learned.

Comment: Thanks Sverri.. i do have a bit of Linux knowledge.. but this was something i didn't know since i usually deploy w/o the need for system folder access. but again, thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access the file via http, just do it like

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://server.addr/path/to/file.ext');
```

if you want to save the content to your *nix OS, make sure that you have the writing permission of the path you're writing to.